# Sort by artist in EMMS with compilation albums?

Tags: emms

I've been using the [Emacs Multi-Media System](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/) and it works pretty well, but one thing i can't figure out how to do is sort by *AlbumArtist*. This is important, because i have many compilation albums and soundtracks.

Is there a way to sort the music browser by AlbumArtist(defaulting to Artist if the file lacks an AlbumArtist tag)? (btw, i am using libtag because the default tag reader didn't work right on some of my files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post offers a partial solution to your problem.  Note that it does *not* do a sort by `AlbumArtist` (hence the "partial"), but it does deal with compilation albums in the browser in a sane way.

You will want to modify `emms-browser-get-track-field-function`, whose doctstring reads:

> Documentation:
>
> *A function to get an element from a track.
>   Change this to customize the way data is organized in the
>   browser. For example,
>   `emms-browser-get-track-field-use-directory-name` uses the
>   directory name to determine the artist. This means that
>   soundtracks, compilations and so on don't populate the artist
>   view with lots of 1-track elements.

Now, `emms-browser-get-track-field-use-directory-name` itself is undocumented (a lot of `emms` is like this, unfortunately).  You can either try to use the built-in function as suggested by:

```
(setq emms-browser-get-track-field-function
      #'emms-browser-get-track-field-use-directory-name)
```

I found the built-in function unsatisfactory for reasons I can't recall (it's been a while since I looked at the source code).  Instead, I rolled my own, which you're free to use/modify as you see fit:

```el
(defun dan-emms-get-artist-from-path (track)
  "Identify artist name from directory name directly below
default directory."
  (let* ((path  (emms-track-get track 'name))
         (base  (expand-file-name emms-source-file-default-directory))
         (trunc (substring path (length base))))
    (car (split-string trunc "/"))))

(defun dan-emms-get-track-field (track type)
  "Sort artists by directory name in EMMS browser (avoids the
compilation albums propagating orphans in the list)."
  (if (eq type 'info-artist)
      (dan-emms-get-artist-from-path track)
    (emms-track-get track type "misc")))

;; make compilations follow from the directory name (no orphans)
(setq emms-browser-get-track-field-function
      #'dan-emms-get-track-field)
```